# How can I display a numpy array with imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

The `np.array` that results from this loop has 4383 lines and 6 columns. I have tried without success to use `pylab.imshow()` from  `matplotlib(pylab)` to display the array.

The objective is to create an image of the array, in which the colors gradient represent the magnitude of the array values.

Each row of the array represents the variation in depth of a lake temperature in each day (4383 days). Thus the objective is to find differences in lake temperatures in depth and with time.

```py
TempLake = np.zeros((N+1,Nlayers))
TempLake[0] = T0

Q = np.zeros(N+1)
Q[0] = 0.0
for i in xrange(N):
    Q[i+1]=Qn(HSR[i],TD[i],FW[i],TempLake[i][0])
    TempLake[i+1] = main_loop(Z,z,Areat0,Areat1,TempLake[i],wind[i],Q[i],Q[i+1])
    
pylab.imshow(TempLake)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `imshow` as follows:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np


Z=np.array(((1,2,3,4,5),(4,5,6,7,8),(7,8,9,10,11)))
im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In your case can you check the output of `TempLake`.

Answer (score 0):

`imshow` is typically used to plot a 2D data. It's worth pointing out that interpolation argument is probably useful when displaying an image. In the following example, the same data is plotted with no interpolation (`interpolation='none'`) on the left and with [gaussian interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) (`interpolation='gaussian'`) on the right.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

TempLake = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5),(4,5,6,7,8),(7,8,9,10,11)])
im = plt.imshow(TempLake, cmap='hot', interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image: imshow]